# Aligning Multiple Instances of JCarouselLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [JCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) to produce three scroll boxes on a website. 2 of the carousels line up properly (`New`, `Gifts)`, but a third does not (`BestSellers`).

The image floats to the left because the plugin keeps calculating the width incorrectly. All three have the same underlying HTML code, but I can't get the `BestSeller` Carousel to line up properly.

I also tried to run it on `window.load`. and have `init` running in the footer.

What am I missing?

**Update**:

Here's the Code that initalizes the Carousel:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $(".rotateNewContent").jCarouselLite({
          btnNext: ".next", btnPrev: ".prev",
          speed: 800, visible: 1 
       });
       $(".rotateBestsellerContent").jCarouselLite({
          btnNext: ".nextBest", btnPrev:
          ".prevBest", speed: 800, visible: 1
       });
       $(".rotateGiftContent").jCarouselLite({
          btnNext: ".nextGift", btnPrev:
          ".prevGift", speed: 800, visible: 1
       });
 });
```

here is the html of the first and second lists.

```
<button class="prev"></button>
   <div class="rotateWrapper"><div class="rotateNewContent">
     <ul class="NewProductList">
                                                   <li class="Odd">
        <div class="ProductImage">
            <a href="#"  ><img src="#" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductDetails">
            <strong>
                          <a href="#">Organic Maple Syrup from Mount Cabot</a>
                    </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductPriceRating">
            <em>$13.00</em>
        </div>
      </li>
  <li class="Even">
    <div class="ProductImage">
              <a href="#"  ><img src="#" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductDetails">
            <strong>
                          <a href="#">Sicilian Marmalades from Marchesi di San 
                          Giuliano</a>
                    </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductPriceRating">
            <em>$15.00</em>
        </div>
    </li>                       
</ul>
</div></div><button class="next"></button>
   <button class="prevBest"></button>
    <div class="rotateWrapper"><div class="rotateBestsellerContent">
       <ul class="NewProductList">
        <li>
            <div class="ProductImage"><a href="#" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductDetails">
            <strong><a href="#">Farro from Rustichella d&#039;Abruzzo</a></strong>
        <em>$8.75</em>
        </div>
        </li>                           
             <li>
        <div class="ProductImage">
        <a href="#" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductDetails">
            <strong><a href="#">Mariage Frères Marco Polo</a></strong>
            <em>$22.00</em>
            </div>
    </li>                   
    </ul>
```

> **NB**: This site is not yet live, please do not shop.

Comment: You may not want to disable shopping if the site isn't supposed to be live...

Comment: good point. i had enabled it to check the cart and forgot to disable again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The middle instance has a width of `135px`, while the left and right instances have a width of `180px`.

**Left Content**:

> ```
> <div class="rotateNewContent" style="overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; position:
>  relative; z-index: 2; left: 0px; width: 180px;">
> ```

**Middle Content**:

> ```
> <div class="rotateBestsellerContent" style="overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; 
> position: relative; z-index: 2; left: 0px; width: 135px;">
> ```

I used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to diagnose the CSS issues.

Comment: those widths are generated dynamically. that is the problem. Why is it not dynamically generating the correct width?

Comment: I added that code to your question, you can delete this comment.

Comment: By the way, that doesn't create the HTML for that div. Does a source PHP file create the HTML?

Comment: i added the html code above. it is generated by the php, but this is the result of the generation. they two are practically identical.

Comment: I think you ought to understand that the HTML by itself couldn't do this, and the JQuery doesn't do this.  It's something in the PHP that is generating the page.  Can you provide the PHP that generates the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

i narrowed it down to the product names. i believe it has something to do with the foreign characters in the names. when i take those products out, the layout resolves correctly. 
--now i have to figure out how to fix that. :-)

the problem was that there were two divs within the li element. i wrapped both within another div and gave it a set width and height. now the plugin uses that div to calculate its size.

thanks for helping me think this through george!